# How to load a public RSA key into Python-RSA from a file?

Tags: python, openssl, rsa, pem

I generated a private and a public key using OpenSSL with the following commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 512
openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -pubout -out public_key.pem
```

I then tried to load them with a python script using Python-RSA:

```
import os
import rsa

with open('private_key.pem') as privatefile:
    keydata = privatefile.read()
privkey = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(keydata,'PEM')

with open('public_key.pem') as publicfile:
    pkeydata = publicfile.read()

pubkey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(pkeydata)

random_text = os.urandom(8)

#Generate signature
signature = rsa.sign(random_text, privkey, 'MD5')
print signature

#Verify token
try:
    rsa.verify(random_text, signature, pubkey)
except:
    print "Verification failed"
```

My python script fails when it tries to load the public key:

```
ValueError: No PEM start marker "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----" found
```

Comment: I think the problem is the format of the public key. If you look closely, the header on the openssl generated public key is, "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----".  The format is X509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo.  The method you are using is looking for PKCS1 format with a header of "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----".

Comment: Would you tell us how to convert X509 to PKCS1 foramt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python-RSA uses the PEM RSAPublicKey format and the PEM RSAPublicKey format uses the header and footer lines:
[openssl NOTES](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/rsa.html#NOTES)

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Output the public part of a private key in RSAPublicKey format:
openssl EXAMPLES

```
 openssl rsa -in key.pem -RSAPublicKey_out -out pubkey.pem
```

Answer (score 15):

If on Python3, You also need to open the key in binary mode, e.g:

```
with open('private_key.pem', 'rb') as privatefile:
```

Comment: Damm! The saviour :P

Answer (score 7):

To load an OpenSSL generated public key file with python-rsa library, try

```
with open('public_key.pub', mode='rb') as public_file:
    key_data = public_file.read()
    public_key = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1_openssl_pem(key_data)
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend


def load_keys(public_key_path, private_key_path):
    with open(public_key_path, "rb") as f:
        public = serialization.load_pem_public_key(
            f.read(), backend=default_backend()
        )
    with open(private_key_path, "rb") as f:
        private = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
            f.read(), None, backend=default_backend()
        )
    return private, public
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate private key by ssh-keygen:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

and generate public key like this:

```
ssh-keygen -e -m pem -f xxx > pubkey.pem
```

http://blog.oddbit.com/2011/05/08/converting-openssh-public-keys/